# Fortran array input

Tags: arrays, input, fortran, ascii, gfortran

I haven't done any Fortran programming for year and it seems I'm rather rusty now. So, I won't provide you with all my failed attempts but will humbly ask you to help me with the following. 
I've got the following "input" file

```
1 5 e 4  
A b & 1  
c Z ; b  
y } " N  
t r ' +
```

It can have more columns and/or rows. I would now like to assign each of these ASCII characters to arrays x(i,j) so that I can process them further after ICHAR conversions. In this example i=1,4, j=1,5, but it can be any No depending on the input file. The simplest example

```
PROGRAM Example
integer :: i, j
CHARACTER, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:) :: A
READ *, A
ALLOCATE (A(i,j))
PRINT *, A
END PROGRAM Example
```

compiles (Example.f95) but

```
cat input | ./Example.f95
```

does not give any output. 
I would greatly appreciate an advice on how to import the afore-mentioned strings into the program as x(i,j) terms of an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the first line and determine how characters there in the line.  Then read the entire file to determine the number of lines.  Allocate the 2D array to hold characters.  Then read the file and parse each line into the 2D array.  There are more elegant ways of doing this, but here you go

```
  program foo

  implicit none

  character(len=:), allocatable :: s
  character, allocatable :: a(:,:)
  integer fd, i, j, n, nr, nc
  !
  ! Open file for reading
  !
  open(newunit=fd, file='tmp.dat', status='old', err=9)
  !
  ! Determine number of characters in a row.  Assumes all rows
  ! are of the same length.
  !
  n = 128
1 if (allocated(s)) then
     deallocate(s)
     n = 2 * n
  end if
  allocate(character(len=n) :: s)
  read(fd,'(A)') s
  if (len_trim(s) == 128) goto 1
  s = adjustl(s)
  n = len_trim(s)
  deallocate(s)
  !
  ! Allocate a string of the correct length.
  ! 
  allocate(character(len=n) :: s)
  !
  ! Count the number of rows
  !
  rewind(fd)
  nr = 0
  do
     read(fd,*,end=2)
     nr = nr + 1
  end do
  !
  ! Read file and store individual characters in a(:,:)
  !
2 rewind(fd)
  nc = n / 2 + 1
  allocate(a(nr,nc))
  do i = 1, nr
     read(fd,'(A)') s
     do j = 1, nc
        a(i,j) = s(2*j-1:2*j-1)
     end do
  end do
  close(fd)
  write(s,'(I0)') nc
  s = '('  // trim(s) // '(A,1X))'
  do i = 1, nr
     write(*,s) a(i,:)
  end do
  stop
9 write(*,'(A)') 'Error: cannot open tmp.dat'
  end program foo
```

Apparently, `GOTO` is verbotem, here.  Here's an elegant solution.

```
  program foo

  implicit none

  character, allocatable :: s(:), a(:,:)
  integer fd, i, j, n, nr, nc

  ! Open file for reading
  open(newunit=fd, file='tmp.dat', status='old', access='stream', err=9)

  inquire(fd, size = n) ! Determine file size.
  allocate(s(n))        ! Allocate space
  read(fd) s            ! Read the entire file

  close(fd)

  nr = count(ichar(s) == 10)             ! Number of rows
  nc = (count(ichar(s) /= 32) - nr) / nr ! Number of columns 

  a = reshape(pack(s, ichar(s) /= 32 .and. ichar(s) /= 10), [nc,nr])
  a = transpose(a)

  do i = 1, nr
     do j = 1, nc
        write(*,'(A,1X)',advance='no') a(i,j)
     end do
     write(*,*)
  end do
  stop
9 write(*,'(A)') 'Error: cannot open tmp.dat'
  end program foo
```

Comment: Did you not find a way to do this without `goto`? For example with a `do` - `exit` loop? Or a `do while` loop?

Comment: I did indicate that there are probably more elegant ways to solve the problem.  More importantly, I don't get hung up on the judicious use of `GOTO`.  If anything you should notice that `REWIND(FD)` should occur within the region of the code bracketed by `GOTO`.  I'll let you think about it.

Comment: I actually like your second solution. Reading the input file as a stream is, in my opinion, a good idea.

Comment: It's still flawed as it assumes that lines terminate with a LF.  Windows uses (used to use?) CRLF.  The string needs to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

In Fortran, it's always best to know in advance how big your arrays need to be. I understand that in your case you can't know.

Assuming that your input is at least formatted correctly (i.e. the columns match up and have only a single space in between them), I've created a code that should in theory be able to read them in an arbitrary shape. (Not quite arbitrary, it assumes that there are fewer than 511 columns.)

It uses two ways:

- It simply reads the first line in at once (1024 characters, hence the 511 limit on columns) then calculates from the length the number of columns
- It then allocates an array with a guessed number of rows, and once it notices that the guess was too small, it creates a new allocation with double the number of rows. It then uses the `move_alloc` command to swap the allocations.

To find when it should end reading the values, it simply checks whether the `read` returns the `IOSTAT_END` error code.

Here's the code:

```
program read_input

    use iso_fortran_env, only: IOSTAT_END
    implicit none
    character, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A, A_tmp
    character(len=1024) :: line  ! Assumes that there are never more than 500 or so columns
    integer :: i, ncol, nrow, nrow_guess
    integer :: ios
    character :: iom

    ! First, read the first line, to see how many columns there are
    read(*, '(A)', iostat=ios, iomsg=iom) line
    call iocheck('read first line', ios, iom)

    ncol = (len_trim(line) + 1) / 2

    ! Let's first allocate memory for two rows, we can make it more later.
    nrow_guess = 2
    allocate(A(ncol, nrow_guess))

    ! Instead of standard input, we're reading from the line we read before.
    read(line, '(*(A1,X))', iostat=ios, iomsg=iom) A(:, 1)
    call iocheck('read first line into vals', ios, iom)

    ! Now loop over all the rows
    nrow = 1
    read_loop: do

        if (nrow >= nrow_guess) then    ! We have guessed too small.
                                        ! This is a bit convoluted, but the best
                                        ! way to increase the array shape.
            nrow_guess = nrow_guess * 2
            allocate(A_tmp(ncol, nrow_guess))
            A_tmp(:, 1:nrow_guess/2) = A(:,:)
            call move_alloc(A_tmp, A)
        end if

        read(*, '(*(A1,X))', iostat = ios, iomsg=iom) A(:, nrow+1)
        if (ios == IOSTAT_END) exit read_loop   ! We're done reading.
        call iocheck('read line into vals', ios, iom)
        nrow = nrow + 1

    end do read_loop

    ! The last guess was probably too large,
    ! let's move it to an array of the correct size.
    if (nrow < nrow_guess) then
        allocate(A_tmp(ncol, nrow))
        A_tmp(:,:) = A(:, 1:nrow)
        call move_alloc(A_tmp, A)
    end if

    ! To show we have all values, print them out.
    do i = 1, nrow
        print '(*(X,A))', A(:, i)
    end do

contains

    ! This is a subroutine to check for IO Errors
    subroutine iocheck(op, ios, iom)
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: op, iom
        integer, intent(in) :: ios
        if (ios == 0) return
        print *, "IO ERROR"
        print *, "Operation: ", op
        print *, "Message: ", iom
    end subroutine iocheck
end program read_input
```

**Edited to add**

I had trouble with the special characters in your example input file, otherwise I'd just have made a `read(*, *) A(:, nrow)` -- but that messed the special characters up. That's why I chose the explicit `(*(A1, X))` format. Of course that messes up when your characters don't start at the first position in the line.

Comment: What happens if you have more that 1024 characters in a line?  My code allowed arbitrary line length.  You also don't need to guess the number of lines.  You an count the lines by simply reading the file (see my answer), and then rewind to do the actual read.  You even have a comment about how convoluted your dynamic resizing is.

Comment: What happens if you have more that 1024 characters in a line?  My code allowed arbitrary line length.  You also don't need to guess the number of lines.  You an count the lines by simply reading the file (see my answer), and then rewind to do the actual read.  You even have a comment about how convoluted your dynamic resizing is.

Comment: First up, You can't rewind standard input. Secondly, rewinding and reading files from hard disk twice is far slower than reading them once. Real world data will be limited somehow. If you occasionally have 1000 columns, make `line` 2000 characters long.

Comment: Ah, I did not notice you're read stdin.  On modern hardware and modern operating systems, it is not slow.

Comment: You have `read(*, ...)` as your first read statement.  You're reading from stdin.   What do you think that `cat input |` is doing?  Oh, and yes, stdin is the C or UNIX or Linux terminology for standard input.

Comment: I prefer the second code because (a) it forms the array as I would expect it: A(i,j) and it prints it out, e.g., "print *, A(3,4)" while the first doesn't; (b) it always has less than 1024 columns (i.e., characters in rows); (c) it makes use of stdin which is essential for piping. Thanks.